# Execute function when html audio player's play button is clicked

Tags: html, audio, playback

Is it possible to detect when the play button in the html5 audio player is clicked?
For example:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="music.mp3"/>
    <source src="music.ogg" />
</audio>
....
....
$('playbutton').on('click', function(e){
    //some functions
});
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're not interested in the act of clicking on the play button itself per se, but rather in the start (or resumption) of playback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like (heh) you're looking for the `play` event.

```
<audio controls id="player">
  <source src="music.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  player.addEventListener("play", function () {
      console.log("it's go time");
  });
</script>
```

For a full list of the available events, at least according to the spec, check out the [WHATWG doc](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mediaevents)

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything... instead of console.log I added alert('playing');, and assigned id="player" to the audio player, no alert pops up when I click play.

Comment: Try it at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/ZubfF/. BTW, are you using an actual file as your source?

Comment: I have no idea why mine is not working. That fiddle works. My code is pretty much exactly like it... yes I'm using an actual sound file. var player = document.getElementsByClassName("sound");
   player.addEventListener("play", function () {
    alert("playing");
   });

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, you need to either attach the event listener to `player[0]` if you just have a single instance, or attach it to each of the nodes.

Comment: I have jQuery library loaded, how come ('.sound').addEventListener("play", function (){ doesn't work? Event listeners can't be added to classes, only variable names?

Comment: If you're using jQuery to attach the events, you use `.on()`, not `addEventListener`. So you need to call that as `$('.sound').on('play', function () {});`, you're missing the `$` in your comment above

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the "on" feature. This is much simpler than assigning a for loop to append "eventlistener" for each element